# how to dynamically config prometheus scrape config

Tags: prometheus

origin file is :

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  evaluation_interval: 5s

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "webgateway"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["192.168.23.131:8004","192.168.24.201:8005","192.168.24.200:8005"]
```

This config works well when testing.

But using `static_configs` tag will lead to hard code which requires to restart prometheus when config file is changed.
So I tried to configure a dynamic way to load the configurations whiout restart prometheus.

here is my new `prometheus.yml`

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  evaluation_interval: 5s

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

scrape_configs:
  file_sd_configs:
  - names: ['./config/service_config.yml']
```

and here is the `service_config.yml`

```
- job_name: "webgateway"
  scrape_interval: 5s
  metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
  - targets: ["192.168.23.131:8004","192.168.24.201:8005","192.168.24.200:8005"]
```

Prometheus will crash and explain the error like this:

```
 ./prometheus --config.file=prometheus.yml
ts=2022-06-30T04:30:49.735Z caller=main.go:450 level=error msg="Error loading config (--config.file=prometheus.yml)" file=/data/prometheus/prometheus-2.36.2.linux-amd64/prometheus.yml err="parsing YAML file prometheus.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 28: cannot unmarshal !!map into []*config.ScrapeConfig"
```

I have tried everything I can imagine to fix this problem according to [official documentation](https://%20./prometheus%20--config.file=prometheus.yml%20ts=2022-06-30T04:30:49.735Z%20caller=main.go:450%20level=error%20msg=%22Error%20loading%20config%20(--config.file=prometheus.yml)%22%20file=/data/prometheus/prometheus-2.36.2.linux-amd64/prometheus.yml%20err=%22parsing%20YAML%20file%20prometheus.yml:%20yaml:%20unmarshal%20errors:%5Cn%20%20line%2028:%20cannot%20unmarshal%20!!map%20into%20%5B%5D*config.ScrapeConfig%22)
but failed...I don't know if `job_names` tag is forbidden in `service_config.yml` and must be configured in `prometheus.yml`.

I have no idea what's wrong with my configuration, Help me Please ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, job name should be declared beforehand:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'node'
  file_sd_configs:
  - files:
    - 'targets.json'
```

See https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/file-sd/

> But using static_configs tag will lead to hard code which requires to restart prometheus when config file is changed.

You can reload Prometheus configuration without restart:

> Prometheus can reload its configuration at runtime. If the new configuration is not well-formed, the changes will not be applied. A configuration reload is triggered by sending a SIGHUP to the Prometheus process or sending a HTTP POST request to the /-/reload endpoint (when the --web.enable-lifecycle flag is enabled). This will also reload any configured rule files.

See https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#configuration

Comment: Thanks alot! the problem was solved by sending `SIGHUP` in linux with `kill -HUP $pid`.